# How to save the model file in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am a new user of gazebo, and I can't find the way to save models into one file or folder. It seems that the save function only save some kind of log file(.sdf) which connected to the model files inside the local gazebo folder, if I send the file to others, they cannot find the model which only exists in my computer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274392/how-to-save-the-model-file-in-gazebo/) by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is gazebo related question. In future post this kind of questions on gazebo [forum](http://answers.gazebosim.org/).

Gazebo uses as default `.sdf` rather than ROS's default `.urdf` format for models. So your `.sdf` model is your actual model. Take a look at sdf format [here](http://sdformat.org/spec).

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on 2017-10-28**:
Thank you for the information!